# cache resulting in shuffle

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In spark , there can be multiple worker nodes and each worker node can have multiple executors.

When we `broadcast` a dataframe in spark, entire dataframe is copied to each executor. However when we 'cache' the data, the partitions of data is persisted across executors within a worker ie. each executor will have few partitions of data, not entire data.

`Shuffle` is movement of data `across worker nodes` or `across executors within same worker node`. So with this, is it fair to conclude that `cache` would result in `shuffle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Cache can only result in `spill` to local disks of Worker where Executor resides, if not enough memory.

Comment: since cache can store data across executors, is not cached data results in shuffle later when referred by operation using cached data?

Comment: No, caching in Spark does not result in a shuffle. Caching simply stores the data partitions in memory across the executors, while shuffle involves redistributing data across different executors or nodes.

Comment: As @thebluephantom says -- `spark.read...load(<some_path>).cache()` by itself won't cause a shuffle. The subsequent **wide** transformations may result in a shuffle though.

Comment: got it. thank you. finally, just to confirm, if the data is redistributed `across executors within same worker node` and not across worker nodes, do we call this shuffle?

Comment: Interesting aside to the question.

Comment: But simple. Shuffling is a mechanism Spark uses to redistribute the data across different Executors - and even across machines. So it also applies to same Worker. Why? Shuffling is about repartitioining data in some way for Executors to process in parallel - on same or other machine. You may have N Executors on same machine. Across machines is more expensive generally.

Comment: May be time to accept the answer?